# Get files out of sharepoint designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to get files out of Sharepoint Designer 2013? If so, how?

Comment: you have to export them...

Comment: Or go to that particular Library and Download a copy.. Like for MasterPages, Stylesheets, Page Layouts etc.. You can to go respective libraries and download a copy!

Comment: ah. new name. new location. one file at a time. Microsoft innovation at work.





if I could open the library in explorer view, that would be fine, but this was going to be my plan B

Comment: Yes, opening in Explorer view will let you copy multiple files.. please select the answer posted, if the comment helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download style library and site asset files go to design manager and click on create design package, where you will get all the files in the form of wsp.
[image: design package]

Answer (score 0):

Go to that particular Library and Download a copy.. Like for MasterPages, Stylesheets, Page Layouts etc.. You can to go respective libraries and download a copy!